# Multiple Check boxes with Multiple Names

Tags: javascript, php, html, sinatra

I have multiple check boxes with multiple names defined as(inline HTML):

```
 echo "<td>"
     echo "<input type = \"checkbox\" name=\"name\" value=\"$name\">";
     echo "<input type = \"hidden\" name=\"user\" value=\"$user\">"; 
 echo "</td>"
```

When this check box is checked and submitted, it will send the name with the corresponding value to another server. I am using Ruby with Sinatra as the other server to receive the information. For those of you familiar with Sinatra, we use the "params" array method. For example, lets say:

```
$name = Bob
$user = Bob123
```

Then when I click submit, I can get the following information by doing this in Sinatra,

```
puts params[:name] #===>Bob
puts params[:user] #===>Bob123
```

This is very simple if only one check box is checked and submitted, but things get complicated when multiple check boxes are checked. Using arrays instead of single variables do not work. My goal is to submit to the server once per every checkbox checked. I did some research and it seems I need to use javascript to do this:

```
print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"; 

function submit_data(){
    if (submit) {
        for each checkbox checked {
            Send data to sinatra
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is `$user` the logged in user?

Comment: Yes but I don't think that is important, it can be any variable that I am trying to pass

Comment: Then that shoud be kept in the SESSION and not shown to a browser. Alternatively put that in the checkbox value and when submitted go get all the user details you want to pass on to another site from your database using that key

Comment: "Using arrays instead of single variables do not work." What exactly does not work? It looks like your actual problem is passing an array of values from the browser to the server in a single request, which is possible, but it is not clearly stated in your question.